# Looking for name of a series to test divergence / convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am from a non-maths background and need some help with terminology.

I have an infinite series of numbers of form

$$a,  a b, a b c, ... $$

where $a$ is my initial number and $b,c$ etc. are my multiplicative factors. The initial number $a$ and the factors $b,c$ etc. are real rational non-zero numbers.

My question is what is the name for this series? (It is not geometric as the factors can be unequal, $a ≠ b ≠ c$, not a power series as there is not exponent of the terms.)

Also, is it possible to check for the convergence of terms in this series? For instance if I calculate the first $n$ terms in the series are there any tests I can apply e.g. [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). Note that I am looking for convergence of the $nth$ term, not convergence of the summation of the series itself.

Comment: This is too vague.  Every string of non-zero rational numbers can be written this way.

Comment: You mean to call this a *sequence* rather than a series.  As for checking convergence of this... consider looking at the logarithm of this.  You have the $n$'th term is equal to $\ln(abc\cdots) = \ln(a)+\ln(b)+\ln(c)+\dots$ and so this question about terms in your sequence converging is exactly the question of the *series of logarithms* converging.  Use standard techniques for this alternate question and convert back to an answer to your original question by raising $e$ to the power of the resulting limit (*if one exists*).

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok, so you are saying if the log series of my multiplicative factors converges. i.e. the summation of the log of the first $n'th$ terms converges. Then as a consequence my sequence will also be convergent?

Comment: Rewriting, rather than using $a,b,c,\dots$ using $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ assuming each $a_i>0$ we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{i=1}^n a_i$ converges iff $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ln(a_i)$ converges and that if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ln(a_i)= L$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{i=1}^n a_i = e^L$.  Note that you may need additional care if some of the values $a_i$ are negative.

Comment: If only finitely many of the terms $a_i$ are negative, then convergence of the terms *after* all of the negative ones matters.  If infinitely many are negative, then your only hope is for the product to tend towards zero, otherwise it would oscillate and not converge.  For that case, consider looking at $\left|\prod\limits_{i=1}^n a_i\right|$ instead which simplifies as $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n|a_i|$

Comment: ok, that makes sense to me. Out of curiousity do you have a link to the proof that a product series converges if the log series of it converges? Also happy to accept this as the answer if you post it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Apologies, I should have stated in the question the terms are *positive* real rational non-zero numbers

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product